# EditUserViewModel needs a DropDownListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Right now I have added a Region to the ApplicationUser model in Identity 2.0

On the UsersAdmin view, Edit action, I have the following stock code to display/edit the Region of the User:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Region, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I make that TextBox into a DropDownList that allows the user to choose from a list of Region names where Regions is part of ApplicationDbContext?

```
public class Region
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        public Region()
        {
            this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view model. In order to render a dropdown you need 2 properties in your view model: a scalar property to hold the selected value and a collection property to represent the list of possible values to be displayed:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Guid SelectedRegionID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

That your controller action will populate and pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.Regions = db.Regions.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.ID.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name,
    });

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and in the corresponding strongly typed view you could use the `DropDownListFor` helper:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRegionID, Model.Regions, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A follow-on question: When I choose a selection from the DropDownList, and then click Save on this EditView, the MyViewModel handed back to the Task<ActionResult> Edit has all zeros for the SelectedRegionId.  How do I get the user's selection of Region back to the controller?

Comment: Can you see the actual payload sent to the server when you submit the form? How does it look like?

Comment: How would I do that?  (using VS2013 with built-in localhost)

Comment: F12 in your browser and look at the network traffic. Or download Fiddler.

Comment: Well, I can see that the items in the list do have actual Guids (i.e. <option value="c684fd71-aa5b-4acd-ac72-5fc14f0e9365">SE</option>)  so they are at least making it to the view via the model, the selectedId just doesn't seem to be getting set when the model comes back.

Comment: Yes, that's why you should inspect what gets sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: Got it... the RequestBody has &SelectedRegionId=03376634-b9c3-4bbc-9113-0e298f493158 in it and that Guid is for the region I selected from the drop down

Comment: OK, this seems fine. The selected value is sent to the server. Can you show the signature of your `[HttpPost]` controller action to which this form is submitted?

Comment: That was the problem.  I didn't have SelectedRegionId in the Bind.  For those following along, it should be: Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Email,Id,SelectedRegionId")]